# what's the antonym of 'post'?

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of ‘*post*’ in the next case?

> Somebody ***posted*** my writing on his website.

Comment: Somebody *removed* [*took down*] my writing from his website.

Comment: Also you could use "deleted".

Comment: There is no well-defined antonym for *posted*.  It would be clearer if you explained what sort of meaning you were trying to express.

Comment: As snailplane says, your question is unclear. The answer could be _downloaded_, or it could be _deleted_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been an avid content writer for years! This has happened to me several times. And every time, when I see someone posting my content/article on their sites without my permission, I request at [Chilling Effects](https://chillingeffects.org/fairuse/faq.cgi) under [DMCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) to ***takedown*** the content. But this word is used *only* if your case is a case of plagiarism. I think you are looking for this word as you mention that *your writing on others website*.

> [A DMCA Takedown is:](http://www.dmca.com/FAQ/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown) When ***content is removed from a website*** at the request of the owner of the content or the owner of the copyright of the content.

If you are using WordPress, it allows you to *post* and *delete* the posts. In that sense, the antonym could be *delete*; we see a *delete* button to remove the post.